# using wget to download pictures results in junk files

Tags: kubuntu, wget, downloads

**commands**:

```
mkdir -p sun-yat-sen && wget --directory-prefix=sun-yat-sen -r  -nd -np -A.jpg -erobots=off http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Yat-sen_University
```

There are several pics on the link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Yat-sen_University,
after the download process,what i get is all those junk jpg files which could not open by my gnome imgae viewer.

so,what is the reason ?
**thanks in advance**

Comment: What happens if you run `file foo.jpg` on one of the downloaded files in a terminal?  If it says it's html, [James's answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35697/using-wget-to-download-pictures-results-in-junk-files/35703#35703) is very likely correct.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has information pages about each image it hosts with the name of that image (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:North_Square_of_SYSU.jpg).  It is probably these pages that you are downloading, when what you really want is the corresponding image (which would be http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/North_Square_of_SYSU.jpg for the previous example).

Comment: thanks for the reply. And do i have to download those manually ?

Comment: I don't know of an automated way to get the full size images associated with the article.  There are a few libraries that can help you interact with Wikipedia that might help, but I don't know of a ready-made solution.